# Delete rows from file if are longer than 150 characters using sed command in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I need to delete all the rows from a file if are longer more than 150 characters.
I'm trying to using sed command in a pyton script using subprocess.call function, but I there is some syntax erro.
Could you hel me please?
Thanks

```
filename =  path+file

cmd = ["sed -i '/^.\{150\}./d' ./"+filename]
subprocess.call(cmd)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "sed -i '/^.\\{150\\}./d' ./path/file.csv": "sed -i '/^.\\{150\\}./d' ./path/file.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sed to achieve your task.

For instance, with python you could first read the file and then output the filtered content back:

```
MAX_LEN = 150

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for line in content:
        if len(line) <= MAX_LEN:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try. but just to learn, could you help me to find out the right sintax using subprocess.call + sed?